# how to retrieve texture information in DirectX?

Tags: directx

How can I retrieve the texture width, height, number of mipmap levels of the texture which has been already created in DirectX? what is the API for it?

Comment: which version of DirectX did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ID3D10Texture2D::GetDesc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), Assume pTexture is a valid pointer to ID3D10Texture2D, then

```
D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
pTexture->GetDesc(&texDesc);
```

Here is the information you can get from texDesc

```
typedef struct D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC {
  UINT             Width;
  UINT             Height;
  UINT             MipLevels;
  UINT             ArraySize;
  DXGI_FORMAT      Format;
  DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC SampleDesc;
  D3D10_USAGE      Usage;
  UINT             BindFlags;
  UINT             CPUAccessFlags;
  UINT             MiscFlags;
} D3D10_TEXTURE2D_DESC;
```